# How to “Save As” a document in macOS? I can only “Save” the document

Tags: macos, save-as, textedit

I am new to macOS computers. I am use to using Notepad on a Windows PC. I make my own invoice using Notepad.

- First I make what I call a header for specific clients with just the info needed to keep from repeating things on a weekly basis.
- When I open the specific header and insert info needed to complete the invoice I can click the “Save As” option in the file drop down and rename this file but I don’t lose the original saved file which is my original header.

My question is: How can I get the same effect using TextEdit on a macOS computer?

I have tried building my initial header page and saving under a specific name, but not found a way to open that saved file, edit its contents and saving as a different name.

When I try to do so the initial header page is not saved to reopen at a later date or time.

Answer (score 3):

TextEdit has **both** Duplicate & Save As… functionality. Both will do approximately the same thing, ie offer you the opportunity to save a new file with a new name.

The difference is that Save As… will save a new file with a new name - but leave the new file as the one you're currently working on & 'invisibly' close the original. If you don't change the name as you do this, you will of course overwrite your original.

Duplicate will present you with a distinctly different document in front of the other, initially called [old name copy]. You then just Save this one. You now have two documents open, not one.

TextEdit & some other Mac apps will use the normal Save As… key command  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>  as Duplicate, not regular Save As… but the other is in the File menu should you specifically need it.

One thing to note additionally if you are not used to Mac is that you can quit & relaunch or reboot at any point during this & both files will re-open exactly as you last left them, even if you didn't save. Only when you close the file will you get the prompt to save.
You must save if you're going to send it to someone else, but so long as you're working on it, it will automatically keep your last edited version [but not the undo queue if you relaunch or reboot].

Lastly, if you are working with what is in effect a Template, then you can protect your original 'master' file so you cannot accidentally overwrite it.
Save your 'master', then go to it in Finder, select the file & hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  or right click > Get Info. In the window that pops up, check the box for Stationery Pad then close the info window.
Then every time you double click your 'master file' to open it, it will automatically open a copy, ready to insert your new information & just Save.

Answer (score 0):

Most MacOS programs do not have a "Save As" function*.

One way to get the same results is to use the "Duplicate" option.

For your situation:

- Type the header into TextEdit and Save (eg. as "Header.txt")
- Click "Duplicate"
- A new window should open called "Header copy.txt" with all the same information
- Add the unique information to this document and Save (eg. as "Invoice 1.txt")

You should then have two documents, one with just the header and another with your additions. You can repeat this by opening your header document and duplicating it again as many times as necessary.

*Many programs add this functionality into their programs (eg. Microsoft Word for MacOS), and in these you will find a "Save As" button, just like on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Most Mac apps use the shortcut <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for „Save as...“.

Many menus will show additional or different menu options while holding down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key.

Source (Apple MacOS User Guide):
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-work-with-documents-mchldc1dd114/mac

> Save a document with another name: In a document, choose File > Save As, then enter a new name. **If you don’t see Save As, press and hold the Option key, then open the File menu again.**

Comment: Save As… is usually SHIFT/Cmd/S

Comment: @Tetsujin: Option/Alt key should be correct. Please look at the source in my improved answer.

Comment: Find me one Apple app that works that way;) Your quote is out of context, or more strictly, doesn't say what the rest of your answer says..

Comment: Easy. TextEdit.
https://support.apple.com/guide/textedit/save-documents-txte71fa0102/mac

>Tip: To save a copy of a document, hold down the Option key, then choose File > Save As. Type a name for the copy, then click Save. You can edit the copy in the open TextEdit window.

Comment: So show me where it says alt/cmd/s for save as. Take a screenshot, like this one… https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NmEr.png or this one with alt held - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGwid.png

Comment: If that's new for Big Sur… then it's actually totally new. That alt/Save As doesn't exist before & makes no difference whether you hold alt or not if you select save as from the menu